# Openfire and strophe.js: not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: apache, xmpp, openfire, strophe

Im trying to create a webchat using Jabber. I have installed Openfire and i can login to the admin panel at :9090 so the server is running.

Now when using strophe.js basic example, coming with strophe.js i get this error:

5XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jabber.xxx.dk:7070/http-bind/. Origin http://jabber.xxx.dk is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

How can i allow the domain?

Comment: For anyone new to this here is a getting-starting tutorial to set this all up, https://expertnotfound.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/setting-up-openfire-bosh-strophe/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @SamGoody for pointing this out.  As of version 3.8.0, OpenFire now supports[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWANu.png) CORS[2], which is needed for your use case.  To enable it, go to the OpenFire admin console, Server, Server Settings, HTTP Binding tab.  Ensure that "Provides support for CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)" is Enabled, with a domain list of `*` (these are the defaults).

[image: OpenFire admin screen]

Comment: OpenFire 3.8.2 is now out, and it has support for CORS.

Comment: Thanks @SamGoody.  Rewrote my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 6):

If it doesn't work even after enabling CORS in Openfire and changing the domain policy to accept all, then check your URL for Openfire. You may need to add '/' at the end (e.g. `'http://dimain:7070/http-bind/'`).

Without the slash it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to setup your apache server to proxy port 7070 so you're not dealing with cross-domain issues per se. The code for that looks something like this inside of your httpd.conf file:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /http-bind http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/
ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you log in to the admin panel, go to the Server Settings tab, then to HTTP Bindings, check both options (HTTP Binding and Script Syntax) are set to Enabled

Comment: They are both enabled, and port is set to 7070.
This is the cross-domain policy:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="5222,5223,7070,7443" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

Comment: is /http-bind/ the default folder? should i do something to create this folder?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't got experience with HTTP binding, only Openfire itself. Now that it's not a simple configuration issue, it's out of my depth but hopefully someone else can provide an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had faced same issue and come to know that port was not open for access.
Though it browser says it is CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue.
This is sometimes open port issue. Please make sure http bind port is open and can be accessible over tcp on system your are testing.

Comment: This should be a comment.